# Deleting entry from MySQL table using PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty sure this question has been asked many times, I've searched the web and still can't figure out the solution to this problem.

Here's the code (I know it is not injection proof):

To display all the entry in the table

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM testimony";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<div>
  <form name="testimonial" action="admintestimony.php" method="post">
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="testyname" value='<?php echo $row[0];?>' readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Testimony:</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><textarea name="txttesty" cols="50" rows="10" readonly><?php echo $row[1];?></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="reject" value="Reject"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

To check whether approve or reject is pressed

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');
$testyname=$_POST['testyname'];
if (isset($_POST['approve']))
{
    header("location:testimonyapproved.php");
}
else if (isset($_POST['reject']))
{
    header("location:reject.php");
}
?>
```

If reject is pressed

```
<?php
session_start();
$testyname=$_POST['testyname'];
include('connection.php');
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimony");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'transaction' WHERE 'transaction' 'name' = $testyname");
header("location:testimonyrejected.php");
?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is vulnerable to injection. Sanitize the input and look into using the mysqli_* functions instead of the mysql_* deprecated ones.

Answer (score 0):

its your SQL

```
 DELETE FROM `transaction` where `name` = $testyname
```

will likely work better

Comment: Thanks, but the entry is still there, it does not delete.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is wrongly formatted (quotes in wrong places).
I've added some comments in this improved code, check it out.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testimony"); //this line is useless and you can delete it
mysql_query("DELETE FROM transaction WHERE name = '".$testyname."'"); //this line contained wrong syntax
```

Please note that mysql_ functions are deprecated in new versions of PHP. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/1422070) on more info on this subject.

Also you might want to prevent SQL injection in the `$testmyname` variable. [This guide](http://bobby-tables.com/) will help you with tat.