# Can't delete certain row from database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

From the beginning. I'm working on a small web application, using PHP. It consists in some kind of notepad, you can write a note and it'll save it for you. My problem is in deleting those notes, **I can't figure out a way to delete the correct note.** I query the database and show everything with a simple loop:

```
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_for_content)){
    echo '
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>' . $rows['title_text']. '</h2>
        <p style="overflow-y:scroll; max-height:150px">' . $rows['txt_mensagem'].  '</p>
        <p style="color:#A0A0A0; font-size:90%;">' . $rows['date_creation'].  '</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" id="row_table" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#open_modal_edit"  role="button">Detail &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>'; 
}
```

As you can see I gave it some simple style, and put it inside a div.

[How note are being shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phnv5.png)

I've been thinking about my problem for some time, googled, asked friends, no luck.

The problem is that I can't figure out the correct query to delete the message. As shown in the picture I have some fields as "Title", "Message" and "Date of creation". I thought about using those field to create the query, but I can't access the fields.

I hope I didn't confuse you, and in case I did, please ask me so I can help you help me :D

Comment: create a button that onclick has a function that you can pass a parameter, this parameter should be the id of the note. The function makes an ajax call and deletes the record from the database

Comment: First you need to figure the solution on your DB, then move the solution to PHP. If your DB have an ID collumn, use it to delete the row.

Comment: @Danielzt But how do I identify the message? For example, imagine I have a message that is in a div and I wanna delete it, how do I build the query using information from my div? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. When you are generating the HTML, put the ID you have on the table, inside the HTML. Like Gautam solution, put the ID dinamically.
<a href="delete.php?uid=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">Delete</a>

Comment: If you have the ID only inside the HTML, set the field ID of the div and get it with jquery. But I think you are looking for first solution.

Comment: @Danielzt Well, I think that is the solution that I need, I'll try to implement it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a new php script. Lets say delete.php

The content of the script may be:

```
session_start()
// Do your session checks and terminate script if user is not logged in....

// UID = lets say that uid is the primary key in your table
$delete_uid=$_GET['uid'];
$con = mysqli_connect(server,username,pass);
$con->query("delete from table_name where uid=$$delete_uid")
```

Just add a link to the script in your notepad passig uid of the note as Get parameter, for example:

```
<a href="delete.php?uid=212">Delete</a>
```

Alternatively you can also make an ajax call to the script. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/what_is_xmlhttprequest.htm

You can read more about this here:

- [Deleting entry from MySQL table using PHP variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867885/deleting-entry-from-mysql-table-using-php-variable)
- [How to get parameters from a URL string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480763/how-to-get-parameters-from-a-url-string)
- [Using sessions & session variables in a PHP Login Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097887/using-sessions-session-variables-in-a-php-login-script)